# Custom URL schemes

Tags: ios, swift

How does one handle custom URL schemes to allow one app to be directed to another? e.g. `instagram://user?username=someusername` which directs a user straight to the users profile via username.  I need to create something similar.

I've checked out `application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool` and `application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool` but they seem to have a red line through when attempting to implement so I assume they are deprecated. Also, they don't seem to get called when I open my app via url from a browser.

Comment: When methods are deprecated the warning usually tells you which method you should use instead.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez no warnings are showing up

Comment: Wherever you saw that it's deprecated, that's where it probably says what to use now. Or you could google the docs for UIApplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this url as an example: `appName://?id=12345`

You can do something in your app once launched using the url like so

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    if let items = urlComponents?.queryItems as [NSURLQueryItem]?,
        (url.scheme == "appName") {
        if items.first?.name == "id",
            let id = items.first?.value {
            print(id) // prints 12345 to console
            // do something with the id, possibly present/push a controller for the user
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 13 and above below function will no longer work.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

Updated function from iOS 13 and above

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)
```

Use this function in **SceneDelegate** class.
Credit: https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/custom-url-scheme-deep-link-ios-13-and-later-swift-5/
For more detail follow [this tutorial](https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/custom-url-scheme-deep-link-ios-13-and-later-swift-5/)