# Custom URL Scheme not working on Swift 5, Xcode 11

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I've added a custom URL scheme to my Xcode project (I'm using SwiftUI).

[image]

In the AppDelagate file I've added:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print(url.absoluteString)
        print("work")
        return true
    }
```

When I to Safari (sampleurlscheme://) in either the emulator or a physical device the code is not being executed (i.e. the logs do not show etc), But it is taking me to the app.

Is there something I'm missing or could this be a bug ?

Comment: it appears that this is being handled in SceneDelegate.swift with function: func ```scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)```

Comment: I was also having this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called)

Comment: Visit here for updated iOS 13 and later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291172/custom-url-schemes/62136667#62136667

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that this is being handled in SceneDelegate.swift with function:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)
```

Comment: How do I call this?

Comment: It should be called automatically, in this function (in SceneDelegate) add whatever logic you need to add. If it’s not in scene delegate add it

Comment: I'm trying to open a url from a view in SwiftUI, any idea how I can go about that? Doesn't seem to be anything online about it

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117348)

Comment: Thanks. I just want to open the link in Safari, I don't need a webview in my app

Comment: how to get the url from this method ? previously we take it from application(open: ..) method's signature

Comment: @JAHelia Just add this to the top of the method: `guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }`